# PDF Viewer with Trim Margins/Crop Feature

Tags: windows, pdf, viewer, crop

The application Goodreader on my iPad has a feature called "crop tool", which comes very handy for reading scientific papers. The following page seems to describe the feature quite well:

http://www.practicallyefficient.com/2011/11/15/fat-pdf/

I would like to use a similar feature on my desktop PC running Windows 7. Unfortunately, I haven't found a free and slim PDF viewer yet that offers this feature in a similar, intuitive way.

Note: I don't want to change the PDF document. I only want to crop the margins to make best use of my small display.

Is there a free and slim PDF viewer for Windows 7 that includes such a "crop feature"? Which PDF viewer on Windows 7 do you prefer for reading scientific papers?

Answer (score 2):

Okular. It's not Windows native though, so you'll have to install the KDE :( But the nice thing is that it doesn't crop the file, it only trims the margins in the view.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was the only desktop application that I can find. It's a shame the question was closed.

Comment: Get the compiled binary from [KDE CI builds](https://binary-factory.kde.org/job/Okular_Release_win64/lastStableBuild/). With Chocolatey it's [`choco install okular`](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/okular). No need to install KDE and compile manually.